# Mono make fails on OS X 10.8.3 due to submodule update failure

Tags: mono, osx-mountain-lion

After checking out Mono source from github and running `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local` with an environment MDK and `monolite` are installed, I tried to `make`, then I got the following error:

```
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in runtime
if test -w /Users/alp/workspace/mono/mcs; then :; else chmod -R +w /Users/alp/workspace/mono/mcs; fi
cd /Users/alp/workspace/mono/mcs && make --no-print-directory -s NO_DIR_CHECK=1 PROFILES=' net_2_0 net_3_5 net_4_0 net_4_5  ' CC='gcc' all-profiles
-n Bootstrap compiler:
Mono C# compiler version 2.10.11.0
make[7]: *** No rule to make target `../../external/ikvm/reflect/*.cs', needed by `../class/lib/basic/basic.exe'.  Stop.
make[6]: *** [do-all] Error 2
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: *** [profile-do--basic--all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [profiles-do--all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It was because `external/ikvm` was empty. So I ran `git submodule init`, it was successful, then I tried `git submodule update --recursive`. That's when I got the error:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'external/Lucene.Net'
```

If I run `git submodule` a minus appears on all submodules except `Lucene.Net`:

```
$ git submodule
 88fb67b07621dfed054d8d75fd50672fb26349df external/Lucene.Net
-471c3e0803a9f40a0acc8aeceb31de6ff93a52c4 external/Newtonsoft.Json
-e77b12e6cc5ed260a98447f609e887337e44e299 external/aspnetwebstack
-fc76b93e3e0064b2d751796878f9cbe88df1d5f4 external/cecil
...
```

Why `git submodule update` is giving me this error?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
rm -Rf external/Lucene.Net/
git submodule init
git submodule update
```